# How to get the same result in single mysql query

Tags: mysql

Right now I use two queries to count the number of contact from certain click.
I've tried a lot of stuff like *left join*, *right join*, *union*, but I can retrieve the expected result.

**The first query**

```
SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnClicks from warehause where userId=8
```

**returns**

```
| offertId | returnClicks |
|    47    |      4       |
```

**while the second**

```
SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnContacts from contact where userId=8
```

**returns**

```
| offertId | returnContacts |
|    47    |        1       |
```

How can I make a single query to get this kind of result?

```
| offertId | returnClicks | returnContacts |
|    47    |      4       |        1       |
```

Don't worry, of course I don't need to count the contacts if I have no returnClick.

Comment: Your queries are [invalid SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) because the column `offertId` that appears in the `SELECT` clause without being aggregated does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Are you sure you don't want to `GROUP BY offertId` in both queries?

Comment: Is there a single value of `offertId` for all rows that have the same `userId`? Otherwise the value you get in `offertId` is indeterminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: your queries are probably<sup>1</sup> invalid SQL because the column `offertId` that appears in the `SELECT` clause without being aggregated does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects<sup>2</sup> such queries. Previous versions process them but they are free to return as `offertId` any value from the column `offertId` that is selected by the `WHERE` condition.

Are you sure you don't want to `GROUP BY offertId` in both queries?

I will assume both your queries contain `GROUP BY offertId` to get the correct results.

---

<sup>1</sup> The queries are valid and return the expected results **if and only if** `offertId` is functionally dependent on `userId`; i.e. all the rows having a certain value in `userId` also share the value of column `offertId`.

<sup>2</sup> Since version 5.7.5, using the default configuration, MySQL rejects the [queries that use `GROUP BY` incorrectly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Previous versions of MySQL used to accept such queries but the values they return for columns that do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause and are not used with [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) were indeterminate.
To let the existing code run, the setting introduced by MySQL 5.7.7 can be turned off. It is not advisable to turn it off if you don't have old queries that run on the server; you better write valid SQL queries in your new code and don't rely on implementation details (they produce indeterminate results anyway).

---

#### The original solution, given the queries are changed to contain `GROUP BY`

You can `JOIN` the results returned by the two queries you already have:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnClicks from warehause where userId=8 GROUP BY offertId
) clicks
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnContacts from contact where userId=8 GROUP BY offertId
) contacts USING (offertId)
```

It will return all the rows generated by the first sub-query and the matching rows from the resultset generated by the second sub-query.

I assume the first sub-query returns in `offertId` all the values returned in `offertId` by the second sub-query. If they do the other way around then just replace `LEFT JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN`.

**Remark:** If the sets of `offertId` values returned by the two sub-queries are not included one into the other then the above query **does not** return all the results you need. In this case you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` (it includes **all** rows from both sides) but, unfortunately, MySQL does not support it.

---

#### The no-`GROUP BY` solution

The op mentioned they don't need to use `GROUP BY`. In this case, each of their original queries returns at most one row. If the values returned in `offertId` by the sub-queries match, the code provided above also works and returns one row that contains `offertId`, `returnClicks` and `returnContacts`. If they don't match (or one of them doesn't return any rows) the final result set will miss the values produced by the second sub-query.

A possible solution to get all the values in the result set is to change the format of the result set.

This query:

```
SELECT 'clicks' as kind, offertId, count(*) as number from warehause where userId=8
UNION
SELECT 'contacts' as kind, offertId, count(*) as number from contact where userId=8
```

produces this result set:

```
| kind     | offertId | number |
| clicks   |    47    |    4   |
| contacts |    47    |    1   |
```

It contains all the rows returned by the two queries, no matter if they return 0 or 1 rows, no matter if the values of `offertId` match or not.

The column `kind` tells what sub-query generated the row, the column `number` tells the value produced by `COUNT(*)` from the corresponding sub-query.

The values can be analyzed, combined, processed in any way in the client code (assuming it is not a stored procedure and a more powerful language is used on the client side).

Comment: "Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects such queries." Minor correction: Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects such queries, **unless you change the default sql mode setting**.

Comment: @Shadow your remark is correct but the default sql mode setting is there for a reason and that reason is to guide/force the developers to go forward and learn how to write valid SQL query and stop relying on implementation details (that produce indeterminate results anyway).

Comment: You do not have to sell me the principle, however, the setting can be changed to allow queries like the above to run.

Comment: @shadow The setting is changeable to avoid breaking the existing code that relies on the old behaviour. It is better to avoid relying on the old behaviour for the new code. I would rather fix my old queries than turning the setting off. But this is just my opinion, everyone is free to act as they think it's best for them.

Comment: Again, I'm not arguing with you. I just pointed out, you incorrectly wrote that from mysql v5.7.5 such queries are rejected.

Comment: I have just a little problem, it returns NULL in returnContacts if there are no contacts, how to force 0 instead of null? Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Use the function [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). I guess you are using the first query, the one with `JOIN`. Replace the global `SELECT *` with `SELECT offertId, IFNULL(returnClicks, 0) AS returnClicks, IFNULL(returnContacts, 0) AS returnContacts`

Comment: Make it `SELECT clicks.offertId, ...`, otherwise MySQL complaints it doesn't know what `offertId` to choose (`clicks.offertId` or `contacts.offertId`).

Answer (score 2):

This is dynamic for all users, using a correlated query.

```
SELECT t.offerTID,count(*) as returnClicks,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM returnContacts s
        WHERE t.userID = s.userID) as returnContacts
FROM returnClicks t
```

You can add a where clause at the end to filter your desired user

If each user has more then one offerTID , then you should add a group by clause like this:

```
SELECT t.offerTID,count(*) as returnClicks,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM returnContacts s
        WHERE t.userID = s.userID AND t.offerID = s.offerID) as returnContacts
FROM returnClicks t
GROUP BY t.offerTID
```

Comment: I like your answer, but we are talking about millions of record... So I can't scroll the entire db just to made another query after.

Comment: Millions of records doesn't mean that it won't be fast if the tables are indexed properly. Besides, the first query with a where clause is what you asked for @Vixed :P

Comment: I voted your answer, but I think that the solution that @GiorgiosBetsos purposed is quite faster than yours. (Tested, I swear)

Comment: @Vixed Its ok:) Glad to be assistant anyway.

Comment: @sagi - Why don't you just add `where userId=8` to make Vixed happy? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.offertId, t2.offertId) AS offertId,
        returnClicks, returnContacts
FROM (SELECT offertId, count(*) AS returnClicks 
      FROM warehause 
      WHERE userId=8
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT offertId, count(*) AS returnContacts 
  FROM contact 
  WHERE userId=8) AS t2
```

Both queries return *always* one row each, so you can use `CROSS JOIN` to bind them.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75224e/3)

Comment: I think this is going to give you syntax error indicating unknown table t1 and t2.

Comment: @Shadow Ok, fixed it, sorry.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It works, but seems to be really slow.

Comment: It just count all click, and all return, but not for each offerId

Answer (score 0):

Combine the 2 queries as subqueries with a join:

```
select t1.offertId, t1.returnClicks, t2.returnContacts 
from 
    (SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnClicks 
     from warehause 
     where userId=8) AS t1
inner join
    (SELECT offertId, count(*) as returnContacts 
     from contact where userId=8) AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM       (SELECT 1 as tmpId, offertId, count(*) as returnClicks from warehause where userId=8) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 as tmpId, offertId, count(*) as returnContacts from contact where userId=8) t2 on t1.tmpId = t2.tmpId
```

You might want to change the query above to a outer join if one or both sides of the join might return no rows.

PS: Posted from my cell, so it might have some minor bugs, since I wasn't able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.offertId,count(a.offertId) as returnContacts, count(b.offertId) as returnClicks from contact a join  warehause b on a.userid = b.userid where userId=8

Comment: Format the code using the `{}` button in the editor toolbar and add a short explanation of what change you suggest and why your solution works. This way you have more chances to get your answer up-voted. As this answer looks now, it have many chances to get flagged as "low quality" and to be proposed for deletion.